# Set linq return property to null

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

How come setting `OrganizationName = null` does not work?  I am doing a union and would like to set the value to `null`.

```
from a in Activities
select new 
{
    a.ActivityID,
    a.ActivityName,
    a.OrganizationID,
    OrganizationName = null
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of questions but no accepted answers. Please amend this.

Comment: Agreed, accepted answers and upvotes help the world go around.

Comment: Nothing more frustrating than answering someone's question only to be blue balled and never hear from the OP again. So I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't actually do this:

> It is a compile-time error for an
>   expression in an anonymous object
>   initializer to be of the null type.

However, you can do this:

```
from a in Activities 
select new  
 { 
  a.ActivityID, 
  a.ActivityName, 
  a.OrganizationID, 
  OrganizationName = (object)null 
 }
```

This is because in an anonymous object it needs to be able to determine the type of that variable, and it doesn't want to assume it is just `object`. In fact for your example you may not even want that (you might want a `string` or a complex type e.g. `Organisation`). This is the same problem as going:

```
var a = null; /* What am I oh cruel world */
```

Having said that I can't see the utility of what you're trying to do here so perhaps if you elaborate on your use-case a more useful answer may be found.

References:

- [C# Version 3.0 Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364047%28VS.80%29.aspx#cs3spec_topic6)
- [Relevant article](http://blargh.tommymontgomery.com/2010/02/setting-null-values-in-anonymous-object-initializer-in-c/)

Comment: FYI: the reason is because the compiler has no way to know what type you want `OrganizationName` to be. Casting it to `(object)` you tell the compiler you want `OrganizationName` to be of type `object`, but you can cast it to any type you like (by the name of the property, I assume you want `string`)

Comment: You can also use default(string) which I've always found to be more intuitive than casting a null.

Comment: @Josh Yeah, although a novice might read `default(string)` as `String.Empty`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the OrganizationName to null assuming that it a property of a like so.
    `a.OrganizationName = null`